# Raphael canvas contained in hidden div doesn't show in Chrome and IE9

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, raphael

I have two Raphael canvases on a page, each containing a SVG drawing. One of them is hidden by default (its container has `display:none`). When I show the hidden container in IE9 or Chrome 17, the canvas is empty. In Firefox and Opera, its contents display fine. I'm confused. What gives?

You can see the problem at http://www.mybgagent.com/search. (The button in the bottom right corner of the map ("view map of Varna") toggles between the two canvases.)

Answer (score 0):

It's showing up empty because (according to the DOM) it doesn't actually have any contents.  My guess is that there's some browser bug that causes Raphael's drawing operations to result in no-ops.

Try having the second div visible while you set it up using Raphael, then hide it once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it - a bug was stopping JavaScript execution before drawing the second map in some browsers, but not in others. How stupid of me not to check the console.